# probability after successful observation

Tags: probability

This might be a simple question but say you have a die with 1-6 as possible outcomes and you are looking for the probability of rolling a 3. This would be $1$ in $6$.

I roll the die once, and I get a 3. Does the probability change for the remaining $5$ rolls?

Comment: No, since any new roll of a dice is independent of previous ones.

Comment: No, each roll is independent of each other.